# Using Heaviside step functions to simplify integral of random variables.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

I am going through Rozanov's "Introduction to probability", c4q9. The problem is set up in the following way:

Two random variables $p_{\xi_1}, p_{\xi_2}$ are given by $p_{\xi_1} = \left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac 1 2 \Bbb e^{-\frac x 2}, & x \ge 0 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{matrix}\right.$ and $p_{\xi_2} = \left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac 1 3 \Bbb e^{-\frac x 3}, & x \ge 0 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{matrix}\right.$.

Let $\eta = \xi_1 + \xi_2$.

Their convolution is:

$p_\eta (y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_{\xi_1}(y-x) p_{\xi_2}(x)dx$.

The first step of the solution uses Heaviside step functions and re-arranges it this way:

$p_\eta (y) = \frac{1}{6}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{y-x}{3}} e^{-\frac{x}{3}}  H(y-x) H(x)dx = \frac{1}{6}  \int_{0}^{y} e^{-\frac{y-x}{3}} e^{-\frac{x}{3}} dx$

It is unclear to me what the process was to get from the convolution to the end stage. My main interest here is to understand how this stepwise function can be applied to simplify such problems.

Comment: Even without reading that book I am pretty sure that it is "Heaviside", not "Heavenside".

Comment: I would recommend a to draw a picture of  the two test functions. u will end up with box with hight one and width $y$, beginning at $0$

Comment: Yes heaviside, ive been writing heaven for an hour now :P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need $H$ to have a single formula $p(x)=\frac 12 e^{-x/2} H(x)$ on all of $\mathbb R$ in order to apply the formula for the convolution. To evaluate the integral you first calculate for each $y$ the product $H(y-x)H(x)=1$, for $0\le x\le y$ and $=0$ else (note the typo $H(x-y)$ instead of $H(y-x)$ in your formula).